# Visual Studio default webform name WebForm1.aspx

Tags: visual-studio, webforms

The default when creating a new WebForm in Visual Studio is WebForm1.aspx

I always change this to Default.aspx.

Is there a way to change the default to always read Default.aspx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own project templates including any content you like (including project settings). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247120.aspx